# template based webpage-PHP

Tags: php, html, template-engine

im trying to create a template based system for a site.
its a really simple page - i need header , footer as templates
im using include_once("filename.html") for calling them.

i really dont know if i am doing it the right way. i am an amateur designer. Pls help me if am wrong?im trying all this as i don want to use a template `engine` ad do it myself.

```
---body.html--

 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>

<?php
 include_once("header.htm") 
?>
:
  :
:"html body code"

<?php
 include_once("footer.htm") 
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: normally you would put everything above `<body>` in `header.php` and the closing of the `</body> </html>` in `footer.php`

Comment: Yup, that's the general idea. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: Please improve the athestetics of your provided code. It has syntax errors and is poorly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it the right way, although I would place a semicolon after the include_once. And usually the `<head>` tags are also in a seperate file so it can be included. If you want a different title for every page you can assign a variable to that

Comment: This is a terrible solution to empower. You use a templating engine to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Normally I would. But the asker said he/she doesn't want to use a template engine

Comment: That's true I didn't see the part where he said that.

Answer (score 0):

that is one way to do it for sure. You may want to consider placing the "global" files (header.htm, footer.htm, etc.) in a folder named 'global' or 'include' or something like that so you can easily identify them. For styling, you may want to also do a master CSS that all of the pages call.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help guys..!!i am still in a confusion as to how all the websites keep their headers and footers the same throughout the their pages. do they use a template engine as well??

Comment: i have master .css since i created each page separately initially. and i have separate .css files for header and footer as well so that when i call them on include_once they get inherited with all the files included in them.

Comment: i would say combine it all into one css but that is your call. If it would make your CSS too big for your liking, then keep em separate if it helps you but that is preference

Comment: and yes, doing an include at the beginning of each page to the header and footer is how you would do it

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a templating engine. Using `includes` are dirty and really just the ***wrong way***.

Checkout http://www.smarty.net/

This will allow you to do stuff like:

```
<html>
<body>
{include file="header.html"}
{include file="{$page}"}
{include file="footer.html"}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes good solution like my workstation.

template html5 files need to open and to close <html> ... </html>
Because Doctype-Error shows same bad way. I recommand completed tags for HTML5 Syntax...... I hope you understand m,y solution...